# Can I send a property and the total sum of another property to the view at once?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have a database where I store Orders of which the model looks as follows:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; } 
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool IsSettledWithSalary { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }        
}
```

So the orders are linked to product (for every product ordered there a new order is made) and to the user that did the order. The property IsConfirmed is true if someone's order is confirmed and IsSettledWithSalary is true if the specific order has been deduced from the salary.

Now I want to make a table that shows the balance and name of a user, i.e., display the name of the user with after it the sum of the orders that are Confirmed but not yet deduced from the salary.

To do this I send the following tuple to the view in the controller:

```
var users = db.Orders.Include(o => o.User)
               .Where(o => o.IsConfirmed == true && 
                                            o.IsSettledWithSalary == false)
               .GroupBy(order => order.UserId)
               .Select(user => user.FirstOrDefault());

var balances = db.Orders
               .Where(order => order.IsConfirmed == true  && 
                                            o.IsSettledWithSalary == false)
               .GroupBy(order => order.UserId)
               .Select(group => group.Sum(order => order.UnitPrice 
                                                    * order.Quantity) );

return View(Tuple.Create(users.ToList(), balances.ToList()));
```

Then in the view I picked up the tuple by using the model

```
@model Tuple<List<Models.Order>, List<Decimal>>
```

and accessing them with Model.Item1 and Model.Item2, and using a foreach loop for setting every user next to the salary in a table.

I find this solution pretty ugly and possibly error prone so that is why I want to create a better query / lambda expression to send to the view.

Is it possible to just send the usernames and balance to the view without making a tuple? And if so, how?

Comment: This seems like the exact reason people use ViewModels

Comment: Use ViewModels and send the finalized properties to the view!

Comment: Viewmodel is quite similar to the tuple in a way. How do I make sure that the balance matches the correct user?

Isn't it possible to send a query in a query (i.e., get the user and do a query for the balance and send the two values linked to each other)? I'm a bit afraid that something goes wrong and the balance is displayed at the wrong user.

Comment: Okay guys I'm becoming a bit smarter and am using a viewmodel now where I put the values in. Thanks!

Comment: Have you got it sorted? I was putting together some code to demo what to do.

Comment: @ColmPrunty well I am working on it but I just came back for some advice. I have difficulty sending all users (I need an overview of all users and not of one user) with a List of Orders and a balance t the view). Looks like Ben below did kind of what I was looking for (except for including a list of users/orders).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a "ViewModel" or you could calculate the property and then stick it on ViewBag/ViewData

Example ViewModel:

```
class OrderTotalViewModel
{
    public string User {get;set;}
    public decimal Total {get;set;}
}
```

Populate:

```
var users = db.Orders.Include(o => o.User)
           .Where(o => o.IsConfirmed == true && 
                                        o.IsSettledWithSalary == false)
           .GroupBy(order => order.UserId)
           .Select(group => new OrderTotalViewModel
           {
                User = u.First().Name, // or u.FirstName etc...
                Total = u.Sum(order => order.UnitPrice * order.Quantity)
           });
```

In view:

```
Name: @Model.User
Total: @Model.Total
```

Comment: How do I make sure the balance matches the right user? I actually want to just be able to do Model.User.Balance. I will do my best to make a viewmodel with a user, list of orders, and a balance.

Comment: thanks a bunch. I do need a List of Users though with the balance for each user attached. Looks like you are getting the value of one user? Or am I mistaken? /edit Aha what you did is exactly what I need. Do i absolutely need a Viewmodel to do that?

THANKS

Comment: It's the easiest way I can think of and probably the most robust... There is another way I can think of but it would mean going to the database once for each user, it's better to get everything you want in 1 query.

Comment: Thanks Ben it works like a charm! Only thing I had to change (except for the path to the name) was that First() should be FirstOrDefault(). Then I send users.ToList() to the view and pick it up there with @model IEnumerable<ViewModels.TransactionViewModel>. Then by just using model.Name and model.Total I have a perfect table and can be close to 100% sure the correct amount is at the correct user.

Comment: Cool. I would have thought you wouldn't need .FirstOrDefault(), just .First()? What goes wrong with .FirstOrDefault()?

Comment: It gives an error about possible null-values and then explicitly states that FirstOrDefault() should be used.

Comment: That's just a warning, after GroupBy there should be no null values. If there really was a null value, then once you access the property after FirstOrDefault - you would get a Runtime Error anyway