# How to refactor my Tuple to a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm

After the response on a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196089/can-i-send-a-property-and-the-total-sum-of-another-property-to-the-view-at-once) where [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2965995/ben) suggested that I turn a Tuple into a ViewModel I was wondering if the same thing can be done with the case below.

In this case I am ordering different orders by date. In the view the orders are displayed below each date. The code works, but I think that again a ViewModel would be more appropriate.

In my Controller I have the following ActionResult:

```
var dates = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Product)
                     .Where(o => o.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId && 
                                 o.IsConfirmed == true && 
                                 o.IsSettledWithSalary == false)
                     .GroupBy(o => o.Date)
                     .Select(date => date.FirstOrDefault())
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);

var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Product)
                      .Where(o => o.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId && 
                                  o.IsConfirmed == true && 
                                  o.IsSettledWithSalary == false);

return View(Tuple.Create(dates.ToList(), orders.ToList()));
```

Then in the view I pick up this model as follows:

```
@model Tuple<List<Models.Order>,List<Models.Order>>
```

and can loop over them by using foreach (item in Model.Item1) and foreach (item in Model.Item2).

I am trying to turn this into a ViewModel but am not sure how I would accomplish this. I can of course place dates and orders in a ViewModel (e.g., DatePlusOrderViewModel) and then send that to the view, but this does not make it that much better.

I hope someone can display me some good habits or suggestions on how to use a ViewModel in this case.

Comment: A view model is usually a specificly crafted class that represents a complete view and which provides all data and logic the view needs to display it. I wouldn’t call a tuple a view model.

Comment: @poke No me neither. I am trying to turn this tuple into one. :)

Comment: I have edited your question. If you are working with `ASP.Net MVC`, please tag your question `[asp.net-mvc]`. Otherwise it is unclear which framework you might be talking about.

Comment: What is wrong with DatePlusOrderViewModel (except for name; drop the plus :)) ?